# MySQL query optimiser showing random behaviour for a query on table with primary and composite indexes

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, query-optimization

I have a MySQL table on which I am executing a query. The query is taking a long time ~15 minutes to return results in some instances but in other instances, it returns results within milliseconds.
The two queries only differ in the value of a column in where clause.

## Table Syntax

```
CREATE TABLE `tests` (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `some_other_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `col_1` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `col_2` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_3` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `created_at_epoch` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at_epoch` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `updated_by` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `version` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `col_4` text,
  `col_5` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `some_other_id_col_1_col_2_idx` (`some_other_id`,`col_1`,`col_2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

***id*** and ***some_other_id*** are created using timestamp and random characters after that, an example of some_other_id is "15632901521370150qGUCAQpVuUWK-bJg"

The table has ~60 million records with ~56 gigabytes of data.

**Please note the value of some_other_id in following queries.**

```
select test.id, test.col_3, test.col_5, test.created_at_epoch, test.col_2, test.col_1, test.col_4, test.status, test.some_other_id, test.updated_at_epoch, test.updated_by, test.version from tests test where test.some_other_id='**VAL_1**' and (test.status in ('activated')) and test.id>='' order by test.id limit 2;
--Executes within milliseconds.
--Explain plan gives key as "some_other_id_col_1_col_2_idx".

select test.id, test.col_3, test.col_5, test.created_at_epoch, test.col_2, test.col_1, test.col_4, test.status, test.some_other_id, test.updated_at_epoch, test.updated_by, test.version from tests test where test.some_other_id='**VAL_1**' and (test.status in ('activated')) and test.id>='' order by test.id limit 1;
--Takes ~14-15 minutes.
--Explain plan gives key as "PRIMARY".

select test.id, test.col_3, test.col_5, test.created_at_epoch, test.col_2, test.col_1, test.col_4, test.status, test.some_other_id, test.updated_at_epoch, test.updated_by, test.version from tests test where test.some_other_id='**VAL_1**' and (test.status in ('activated')) and test.id>='' order by test.id limit 3;
--Executes within milliseconds.
--Explain plan gives key as "some_other_id_col_1_col_2_idx".

select test.id, test.col_3, test.col_5, test.created_at_epoch, test.col_2, test.col_1, test.col_4, test.status, test.some_other_id, test.updated_at_epoch, test.updated_by, test.version from tests test where test.some_other_id='**VAL_2**' and (test.status in ('activated')) and test.id>='' order by test.id limit 2;
--Takes ~14-15 minutes.
--Explain plan gives key as "PRIMARY".

select test.id, test.col_3, test.col_5, test.created_at_epoch, test.col_2, test.col_1, test.col_4, test.status, test.some_other_id, test.updated_at_epoch, test.updated_by, test.version from tests test where test.some_other_id='**VAL_2**' and (test.status in ('activated')) order by test.id limit 2;
--Takes ~14-15 minutes.
--Explain plan gives key as "PRIMARY".

select test.id, test.col_3, test.col_5, test.created_at_epoch, test.col_2, test.col_1, test.col_4, test.status, test.some_other_id, test.updated_at_epoch, test.updated_by, test.version from tests test where test.some_other_id='**VAL_2**' and (test.status in ('activated')) and test.id>='' limit 2;
--Executes within milliseconds.
--Explain plan gives key as "some_other_id_col_1_col_2_idx".
```

I am not able to understand the behaviour here and am looking for some explanation on how this could happen.
I am using MySQL 5.6

Comment: as InnoDB stores col_4 text in a separated table away from the rest of the table data meaning extra disk i/o is required to check/fetch the text data... But is the server dedicated into running MySQL only or is a cloud based MySQL server on Amazon or Google as those "random" big difference for basically reading the same RAM/Disk pages as in a few milliseconds to 15 minutes as timing difference in performance is much to wierd..

Comment: Can you place the complete explain and or `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ..` structure which @RickJames also suggested ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this composite index:

```
INDEX(status, some_other_id, id)  -- in this order
```

With 56GB of data, you should seriously consider normalization and other techniques for shrinking the table size.  `status` is a prime candidate for such.  `TINYINT UNSIGNED` takes only 1 byte and provides 256 values.  `ENUM` may be a viable alternative.

`updated_by` is another likely thing to shrink.

If those `epochs` are only to-the-second, don't use an 8-byte `BIGINT`.

To investigate the performance anomolies further, please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` for each, and also the "optimizer trace".